# Clarification sought on Active Record Query Interface 3.0 implications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm taking a look at updating from the deprecated (in Rails 3.1) use of find, to Active Record Query Interface 3.0.

I understand from the [always excellent] RailsCasts [Episode #202](http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3) that find calls need to be rewritten.

However, I'm not clear if it will still possible to use the construct,

```
Products.find_all_by_available(true)   # find specified via method used

# ^ not sure what the name for that convention is
```

...under Rails 3.2, or does this code need to be rewritten in the new format too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine but it's recommended by some people to create named scopes for that, one reason to do so it's the lazy loading, that find and all methods don't use.

you would have something like

```
scope :availables, lambda { |available| where(available: name)}
```